# Adding thumbnail while inserting Live broadcast using YouTube data API not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I tried to add thumbnail with youtube data api while creating live broadcast. Broadcast is created successfully but issue with thumbnail its show youtube default thumbnail not mine.

here is request body: for url i am using public url:

```
{"status": {
   "privacyStatus": "public"
 },
 "snippet": {
"scheduledStartTime": "2021-04-14T06:25:08.000Z",
"title": "testing  thumb",
"thumbnails": {
        "default": {
    "url": "https://i.ibb.co/60vkQqK/nokia.png",
    "width": 120,
    "height": 90
  },
  "medium": {
    "url": "https://i.ibb.co/60vkQqK/nokia.png",
    "width": 320,
    "height": 180
  },
  "high": {
    "url": "https://i.ibb.co/60vkQqK/nokia.png",
    "width": 480,
    "height": 360
  },
  "standard": {
    "url": "https://i.ibb.co/60vkQqK/nokia.png",
    "width": 640,
    "height": 480
  },
  "maxres": {
    "url": "https://i.ibb.co/60vkQqK/nokia.png",
    "width": 1280,
    "height": 720
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the docuentation you cant set thumbnail https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert  even if you could set the thumbnail i would expect it to have to be uploaded not hosted on aother site.

Comment: @DaImTo, Thanks for quick reply. I check this documentation I thought it can support any other hosted site public image URL. The document does not clear the thumbnail image url property

Comment: Probably because google only documents what is supported.   If you check the documentation it doesnt say you can upload send thumbnails with the insert, which implies its not supported.

Comment: Actually i am using api explore and when i click on + icon it show thumbnail property then i was trying this approach https://prnt.sc/11dfb6l . and thanks your mentioned approach is working fine now i am able to set the thumbnail in my broadcast video

Comment: Just because you can insert it does it in fact use it?  I dont think Google is going to let you use a third party link.  They are probably protecting against that.

Comment: yes I agree  with this statement

Answer (score 1):

You can add thumbnails with the Youtube Data API after the stream is created. You have to upload the thumbnail with set. See the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set